# Python how transform group of n elements from list to their mean

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, vectorization

I have a list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

And I want to get the mean out of segments of 3 elements. If the last group of elements doesn't divide in 3, just take the mean of what's remains:

```
new = [2,5,8,10.5]
```

What is the best way to do it? In terms of computation speed (As the obvious for loop will be slow for big lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Using `lists` and `numpy.mean`**:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
l = [l[x:x+3] for x in range(0,len(l),3)]
new = [np.mean(lst) for lst in l]

print(new)
```

**Output:**

```
[2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5]
```

**Performance:**:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| List Length | Time Taken (s) |
+-------------+----------------+
|     1000    |      0.01      |
|    10000    |      0.05      |
|    100000   |      0.50      |
|   1000000   |      5.65      |
+-------------+----------------+
```

**2. Using `numpy arrays` and `numpy.mean`:**

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
l = [l[x:x+3] for x in range(0,len(l),3)]
new = [np.mean(lst) for lst in l]

print(new)
```

**Output:**

```
[2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5]
```

**Performance:**

```
+-------------+----------------+
| List Length | Time Taken (s) |
+-------------+----------------+
|     1000    |      0.005     |
|    10000    |      0.03      |
|    100000   |      0.28      |
|   1000000   |      2.30      |
+-------------+----------------+
```

**The second method is much faster than the first method. Hence, I strongly advice you to go with the second method.**